# QML ToolTip for Component

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make a `ToolTip` for a delegate `Component` in a `TableView`. It works fine, if I use an `ItemDelegate`, however, I cannot use an `ItemDelegate` as it destroys the selection mode of `TableView`. If I try to define the `ToolTip` in my delegate component I get the error

```
 qrc:/FileSystem.qml:34 Invalid component body specification
```

How can I use a ToolTip for a `Component`?

Here is my code:

```
TreeView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    sortIndicatorVisible: true
    model: fileSystemModel
    rootIndex: rootPathIndex
    selection: sel
    selectionMode: 2
    Component {
        id: mycomp
        Row{
            id: myrow
            CheckBox{
                id: cbox
                anchors.baseline: ctext.baseline
            }
            Text{
                id: ctext
                text: styleData.value
                color: styleData.textColor
                width: namecolumn.width-cbox.width-myrow.x
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
        }
        NC.ToolTip {
            parent: mycomp
            visible: hovered
            delay: 1000
            text: qsTr(styleData.value)
        }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        id: namecolumn
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"

        resizable: true
        width: parent.width-sizeWidth-dateWidth-scrollBarWidth
        delegate: mycomp

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A component must consist of exactly one "child". So you could try to wrap the contents of the component into an Item, something like this:

```
Component {
    Item {
        width: parent.width
        height: myrow.height

        Row{
            id: myrow
            CheckBox{
                id: cbox
                anchors.baseline: ctext.baseline
            }
            Text{
                id: ctext
                text: styleData.value
                color: styleData.textColor
                width: namecolumn.width-cbox.width-myrow.x
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: true
            hoverEnabled: true
        }
        NC.ToolTip {
            visible: mouseArea.containsMouse
            delay: 1000
            text: qsTr(styleData.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A further thing: With this solution the mouse area blocks the selection mode of the TableView.

Comment: I will file a new question about this

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Have a look at the acceptedButtons property of the MouseArea: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#acceptedButtons-prop. Just set it to Qt.NoButton. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, maybe post the answer here, as I already filed a new question (maybe a bit too fast) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103461/treeview-delegate-with-mousearea-propagate-mouse Yes, Qt.NoButton does the trick :-)